# How to recover from - can't read superblock error - after using lvreduce command (CENTOS7 XFS)

Tags: restore, xfs

I was attempting to reallocate unused disk space (1.2Tb) from `/dev/mapper/centos-home` to `/dev/centos/root` using the steps in [How to move disk space from centos-home to centos-root](https://serverfault.com/questions/765302/how-to-move-disk-space-from-centos-home-to-centos-root).

After running...

```
$ umount /dev/mapper/centos-home
$ lvreduce -L 1200G /dev/mapper/centos-home
```

I'm getting a "can't read superblock" error when i try to remount the drive.

```
$ mount /dev/mapper/centos-home
mount: /dev/mapper/centos-home: can't read superblock
```

Before starting, I double-checked to make sure there w enough free (physical space) before running the 'lvreduce' command (there was 2Tb free) - but assume my error was not running a command to first shrink the file system as suggested in [LVM logical volume partition corrupted after lvreduce](https://serverfault.com/questions/433275/lvm-logical-volume-partition-corrupted-after-lvreduce), but also read that this can't be done on XFS systems pr have been unable to locate the specifics.

I tried to recover using,

```
$ xfs_repair /dev/mapper/centos-home
```

but the result said

```
Sorry, could not find valid secondary superblock; Exiting now.
```

I also tried to restore the size of the LV

```
$ lvextend -L 1200G /dev/mapper/centos-home
```

with the result,

```
New size (307200 extents) matches existing size (307200 extents)
```

but got the same `superblock read` error when trying to `$ mount` the drive.

I'm not sure how deep of a hole I have dug for myself at this point, so here's my question.

**What's the best way to recover from this?** Or, if I can't recover and mount the damaged drive, do I just delete it and create a new one with the same name? And is this even possible, i.e. do I need to reinstall CentOS? I didn't back up this drive as I haven't been using it. I used the PLESK backup tool so could restore that way, but assume this only works on the `/dev/centos/root` drive so wouldn't apply here?

I have 4 physical disks set up as RAID5. The other drives and applications are running fine (PLESK lives on `/dev/centos/root`) and I don't want to damage them.

I'd also like to complete the original task of growing `/dev/centos/root`.

Here's where things are now....

```
$ pvscan
  PV /dev/sda3   VG centos          lvm2 [2.04 TiB / 838.63 GiB free]
  Total: 1 [2.04 TiB] / in use: 1 [2.04 TiB] / in no VG: 0 [0   ]

$ vgscan
  Reading volume groups from cache.
  Found volume group "centos" using metadata type lvm2

$ lvscan
  ACTIVE            '/dev/centos/swap' [4.00 GiB] inherit
  ACTIVE            '/dev/centos/home' [1.17 TiB] inherit
  ACTIVE            '/dev/centos/root' [50.00 GiB] inherit


$ pvdisplay
  --- Physical volume ---
  PV Name               /dev/sda3
  VG Name               centos
  PV Size               2.04 TiB / not usable 0
  Allocatable           yes
  PE Size               4.00 MiB
  Total PE              535714
  Free PE               214690
  Allocated PE          321024
  PV UUID               qISA9P-0jFe-gk9I-5uuL-OODW-N3af-OkfJlB

$ vgdisplay
  --- Volume group ---
  VG Name               centos
  System ID
  Format                lvm2
  Metadata Areas        1
  Metadata Sequence No  6
  VG Access             read/write
  VG Status             resizable
  MAX LV                0
  Cur LV                3
  Open LV               2
  Max PV                0
  Cur PV                1
  Act PV                1
  VG Size               2.04 TiB
  PE Size               4.00 MiB
  Total PE              535714
  Alloc PE / Size       321024 / 1.22 TiB
  Free  PE / Size       214690 / 838.63 GiB
  VG UUID               zzLRUZ-96Vd-5NGr-YsCl-PJ0l-O8Sy-07Dbqu


$ lvdisplay
  --- Logical volume ---
  LV Path                /dev/centos/swap
  LV Name                swap
  VG Name                centos
  LV UUID                Dxqf6A-Jtyp-Qdhx-1C0u-CS40-L95c-qF4tRU
  LV Write Access        read/write
  LV Creation host, time localhost.localdomain, 2016-12-20 09:00:45 -0500
  LV Status              available
  # open                 2
  LV Size                4.00 GiB
  Current LE             1024
  Segments               1
  Allocation             inherit
  Read ahead sectors     auto
  - currently set to     256
  Block device           253:1

  --- Logical volume ---
  LV Path                /dev/centos/home
  LV Name                home
  VG Name                centos
  LV UUID                9QYG2p-0Srl-AluZ-qsBE-wCQ4-BXyN-0hmTp3
  LV Write Access        read/write
  LV Creation host, time localhost.localdomain, 2016-12-20 09:00:46 -0500
  LV Status              available
  # open                 0
  LV Size                1.17 TiB
  Current LE             307200
  Segments               1
  Allocation             inherit
  Read ahead sectors     auto
  - currently set to     256
  Block device           253:2

  --- Logical volume ---
  LV Path                /dev/centos/root
  LV Name                root
  VG Name                centos
  LV UUID                WrqVSs-EkZI-WD7W-AfsL-2PFX-iZLy-8TPjZr
  LV Write Access        read/write
  LV Creation host, time localhost.localdomain, 2016-12-20 09:01:40 -0500
  LV Status              available
  # open                 1
  LV Size                50.00 GiB
  Current LE             12800
  Segments               1
  Allocation             inherit
  Read ahead sectors     auto
  - currently set to     256
  Block device           253:0
```

Comment: I hope I didn't mangle something while reformatting the text using Markdown markup. Steve, you may want to double-check just to be sure.

Comment: stop making changes NOW. You need to roll back the LV with its archive file.

Comment: Thankfully, this is answered here: https://serverfault.com/a/223400/344497

Answer (score 3):

SmallLoanOF1M, thanks for the suggestion. Because in my case I didn't need to recover the data on the `/home` logical volume (I appreciate this is an exception for most), I followed the instructions [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/634076/shrinking-or-removing-home-partition-in-centos-7-installation?rq=1) and simply removed it using the `lvremove` command.

```
$ lvremove -v /dev/centos/home
```

Which returned the remaining free space to the volume group.

I then used the `lvextend` to extend the `/root` lv

```
$ lvextend -L +900G /dev/centos/root
```

And

```
$ xfs_growfs /dev/centos/root
```

To extend the file system in the now larger LV. Next time I install centos7 for a plesk application, I'll be sure to allocate more than 50G to `/root`, which is the default setting.

Answer (score 0):

xfs_repair /dev/mapper/centos-home -L

this commands will fix the problem

Comment: Can you explain that?

Answer (score 0):

Once you reduce the LV size then you have to reduce the file system as well.

1st: check the file system it there is any error
e2fsck -f /dev/mapper/centos-home

2nd: resize the file system
resize2fs /dev/mapper/centos-home 1200G

3rd: mount

Comment: e2fsck needs the superblock to work

Answer (score -1):

If you don't care about your data in /home, do below:

mkfs.xfs -f /dev/mapper/cl-home
mount /dev/mapper/cl-home /home/

Comment: This is a dangerous suggestion without a lot more context.